# logp in stochastic variables of pymc

Tags: python, distribution, pymc, mcmc

I have a very intrinsic confusion regarding logp. I will like to explain through anexample on na webpage so that I don't fall short of explaining it well.

I wrote disaster_model.py as illlustrated in this tutorial:
http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/tutorial.html

I launched a python shell and after importing all required modules, I did the following

```
In [2]: import disaster_model
Out[2]: -2.9780301980174

In [3]: disaster_model.switchpoint.logp
Out[3]: -4.709530201312334

In [4]: disaster_model.late_mean.logp
Out[4]: -2.407183392124894

In [5]: disaster_model.early_mean.logp
Out[5]: -2.9780301980174

M = MCMC(disaster_model)
M.sample(iter = 10000, burn = 1000, thin = 10)

In [11]: M.switchpoint.logp
Out[11]: -4.709530201312334

In [12]: M.early_mean.logp
Out[12]: -3.2263189370368117

In [13]: M.late_mean.logp
Out[13]: -0.9012784557735074

In [14]: M.disasters.logp
Out[14]: -164.37141285002255
```

I will reemphasize the line (written in disaster_model.py)

`disasters = Poisson('disasters', mu=rate, value=disasters_array, observed=True`

Hence value of disasters is never going to change.

Now my question is

1) **Why did log probabilities change of every variable except switchpoint?**

(Kindly explain why the log probabilties should change, and if they should, then why swithpoint's didn't)

2) **What do old and new log probabilities represent ?**

(It was ipython shell and not python, but it hardly matters)

Answer (score 1):

Rather late reply, but anyway. Your questions.

**1) Why did log probabilities change of every variable except switchpoint?**

The `logp` property gives the log-probability of a variable, given its parents.  The prior distribution of `switchpoint` is a discrete uniform distribution from 0 to 110 years, and its parents are the lower and upper bounds of the uniform distribution. No matter what value of `switchpoint` is considered, its probability mass is 1/111, so its prior log-probability is ln(1/111) = -4.70953, and this will never change.

The log-probabilities change for the other variables (`early_mean` and  `late_mean`) as the MCMC algorithm hops through the space of stochastic variables because their prior distributions are defined as exponential, not uniform.

**2) What do old and new log probabilities represent ?**

In your question, the log-probabilities represent the log-prior probability of the stochastic variables `early_mean`, `late_mean` and `switchpoint`, for their "current" values. You can verify this yourself for `early_mean` by evaluating `np.log(scipy.stats.expon.pdf(M.early_mean.value, scale=1))` and comparing with `M.early_mean.logp`. Note the scale parameter in the exponential distribution reflects the scale parameter defined in `disaster_model.py`.